# Google detects invalid keywords on my site

Tags: keyword, google-search-console

I have a question about keywords detection used by webmaster tools.

Google detects invalid keywords on my site like "to", "for", "and" etc.

That words used repeatedly in all of internet sites. It seems that google ignore my keywords meta tag. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keywords meta tag should contain a list of keywords related to the content of your site, not sentences or generic words like "to" or "for".

Modern search engines don't take that tag into account much anyway.

Comment: I know. My keywords meta tag contains only a list of keywords related to the content of my site. But google webmaster tools detects another words as my keywords.